How to create index.js or any file using VS Code's terminal (powershell) or cmd on Windows?
How to create index.js or any file using VS Code's terminal (powershell) terminal or cmd on Windows?
I tried touch index.js but the error is saying the touch command is not recognised by my terminal in Windows 10.

touch : The term 'touch' is not recognized as the name of a cmdlet, function, script file, or operable program. Check the spelling of the name, or if a path
was included, verify that the path is correct and try again.


Please help me with this.

This question isn't about VS Code. You are using its terminal but VS Code just your OS's default terminal, which from your screenshot is the Windows Powershell.

In Windows the touch index.js command will not work. The touch command works only in UNIX-based OS.
Try this instead..
type nul > index.js


The touch command is a native command on Unix-based systems (macOS and Linux), and it does not work on Windows.
You can use the type command to create a new file. For example:
type nul > index.js

You can also use echo and copy command, but it's only available in cmd, not in PowerShell, while the type command works on both.
Note: nul is a way to represent a nonexistent file or a file that doesn't contain any meaningful data.

There is an npm package called touch-cli which will allow us to use touch command.
Open up your terminal(command prompt) and paste the following code in it.
npm install touch-cli -g

Then run the touch command
touch index.js

